# What is wrong with my shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I built randomForest:

```
library(randomForest)
data(iris)

names(iris)

rF <- randomForest(Species~Sepal.Length+Petal.Width,data=iris)
```

here is interface:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId="Sepal.Length",
              label="Sepal.Length",
              value=6,min=4.3,max=7.9)
  ,
  sliderInput(inputId="Petal.Width",
              label="Petal.Width",
              value=1,min=0.1,max=2.5)
  ,
  textOutput(outputId="rfScor")

)
```

here is server:

```
server <- function(input,output){

  #tabelka do predykcji
  dt <- reactive({data.frame(Sepal.Length= as.numeric(input$Sepal.Length),
                   Petal.Width=as.numeric(input$Petal.Width)
  )})

  output$rfScor <- renderText({predict(rf,dt)})
}
```

and call app:

```
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default: nie można przekształcić klasy ""reactive"" w klasę "data.frame"
Stack trace (innermost first):
    86: as.data.frame.default
    85: as.data.frame
    84: predict.randomForest
    83: predict
    82: renderText [#8]
    81: func
    80: origRenderFunc
    79: output$rfScor
     4: <Anonymous>
     3: do.call
     2: print.shiny.appobj
     1: <Promise>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you the first, though you also have another hidden in there. When you want the results of a `reactive` you need to call it as a function -- with `()` after it. In addition, you need to capitalize the "F" in `rF`.

Change `output$rfScor` to this and it should work

```
output$rfScor <- renderText({predict(rF, dt() )})
```